# Can anyone explain why this str_split behaves so strangely here?

Tags: php

```
function smallest($n){
return str_split($n);
}

print_r(smallest(1896957345795157));
```

the output is an array with . E and + and I don't understand why. While it works for smaller numbers it fails for longer ones

Comment: Maybe when it converts it to a string to split it, it is using scientific notation.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want you can try to [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) your number to string

```
function smallest($n){
    return str_split((string)$n);
}

print_r(smallest(1896957345795157));

//Array
//(
//    [0] => 1
//    [1] => 8
//    [2] => 9
//    [3] => 6
//    [4] => 9
//    [5] => 5
//    [6] => 7
//    [7] => 3
//    [8] => 4
//    [9] => 5
//    [10] => 7
//    [11] => 9
//    [12] => 5
//    [13] => 1
//    [14] => 5
//    [15] => 7
//)
```